# How to fill out struct array in C using pointers?

Tags: c, pointers, struct, iteration

I am trying to to print out the details a user inputs for a review of a restaurant, I want it to print out the details of multiple but my code only prints the last entry.

**Here is an example of input:**

```
Enter Number of reviews: 2  
Enter Your Name: Bob  
Enter Name of restaurant: Ramon Ramen Shoo  
Enter address of restaurant: #15 Orange Gold Street  
Enter phone number: 19178089323  
Enter score: 70  

Enter Your Name: Bill  
Enter Name of restaurant: McDonalds  
Enter address of restaurant: #7 Goldy Street  
Enter phone number: 19132089323  
Enter score: 4
```

And I would like for it to print out the details of both reviews, but only the last entry is printed repeatedly instead of printing both the details of entry 1 and entry 2.

**Here is my code:**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#define MAX_REVIEWS 1000000
#define MAX_SIZE 1024
typedef struct Review{
    char reviewer_name[MAX_SIZE];
    char restaurant_name[MAX_SIZE];
    char restaurant_address[MAX_SIZE];
    char phone[10];
    int score;
}review;
void fill_out_review(review *rp){
    printf("Enter your name: ");
    fgets(rp -> reviewer_name, 1024, stdin);

    printf("Enter name of restaurant: ");
    fgets(rp -> restaurant_name, 1024, stdin);

    printf("Enter address of restaurant: ");
    fgets(rp -> restaurant_address, 1024, stdin);

    printf("Enter Phone Number: ");
    fgets(rp -> phone, 11, stdin);

    printf("Enter score: ");
    scanf("%d", &rp -> score);
    getchar();

    rp++;
}

void print_details(review *rp){
    printf("\n\nName of reviewer: %s\n", rp -> reviewer_name);
    printf("Name of restaurant: %s\n", rp -> restaurant_name);
    printf("Address of restaurant: %s\n", rp -> restaurant_address);
    printf("Phone Number: %s\n", rp -> phone);
    if(rp -> score > 100 || rp -> score < 0 ){
        printf("Error: INVALID SCORE!");
    }
    else{
        printf("Score: %d\n", rp -> score);
    }
    rp++;

}
int main(){
    //review rev1[MAX_REVIEWS] = {{{0}, {0}, {0}, {0}, 0}};
    review rev1;
    review *ptr = NULL;
    ptr = &rev1;
    int num_reviews;

    printf("Enter Number of reviews: ");
    scanf("%d", &num_reviews);
    getchar();

    for(int i = 0; i < num_reviews; i++){
        fill_out_review(ptr);

        //ptr++;
    }
    ptr = &rev1;

    for(int i = 0; i < num_reviews; i++){
        printf("\n\nDetails of review %d:", (i+1));
        print_details(ptr);

        //ptr++;
    }





}
```

Comment: Why do you have the declaration of `rev1` as an array and `ptr++;` commented out?

Comment: Style guide: the dot `.` and arrow `->` operators bind very tightly
because they are [postfix operators](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.5.2.3).
They should not be written with spaces around them.
Writing `rp -> score` is not idiomatic C and indicates that the coder
is a tyro (newbie).  Use `rp->score`.

Comment: If you read two reviews into the same structure, only the second one can be seen because the first was overwritten.  You need an array of structures, like you have commented out — and then use it.

Comment: And if you uncomment the array, it will likely be too big for the stack. You could move it to the global scope, but I think dynamic allocation of just what you need would be the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

You are overwritting using pointer, you can do this operation simply by defining a pointer array.

```
int num_reviews;
printf("Enter Number of reviews: ");
scanf("%d", &num_reviews);

review *ptr=malloc(sizeof(review)*num_reviews);//dynamically pointer array.
review *first=ptr;//take the beginning address.
getchar();

for(int i = 0; i < num_reviews; i++){
    fill_out_review(ptr);
    ptr++;
}
   
ptr=first; //to print all elements, back to the first element.
for(int i = 0; i < num_reviews; i++){
    printf("\n\nDetails of review %d:", (i+1));
    print_details(ptr);
    ptr++;
}
```